# How do I get a JID from a known gmail address using node-xmpp (or similar node project)

Tags: node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp

I'm building a simple instant messenger for my website using node-xmpp.  I have gmail addresses of people who have registered but often these don't match up to the users JID.  For example their email address might be 123@gmail.com but their jid is more like 18777kozzj365i7blahblah@public.talk.google.com

Is there a way to get the JID from a known gmail address?

Comment: You mean from providers that offer XMPP and email, but not using the same local-part/host? (e.g., user Bob has an account at example.com, which gives him the email address `mailto:bob@example.com` and the JID `xmpp:bob@xmpp.example.com`). If so, this would of course depend on the specific provider, no?

Comment: hmm, correct.  I'm talking specifically about google talk but I suppose it is more open than I was meaning.